# How to update DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

The DataContext of the app is bound to my MainViewModel. This ViewModel has a property services and some other properties. When I start a service I want to call `OnPropertyChanged("Services")` inside my `StartService()` and `RefreshServices()`but it is not updating.

My XAML/DataGrid:

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="8"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Services}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  IsReadOnly="True">

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Display Name"  Binding="{Binding DisplayName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Status, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Machine Name" Binding="{Binding MachineName, Mode=OneWay }" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Can Stop" Binding="{Binding CanStop, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

**My ViewModel:**

```
namespace ServiceStarterPRAT.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        #region Services Properties
        private ObservableCollection<ServiceController> _services;
        private ObservableCollection<ServiceController> _selectedServices;

        public ObservableCollection<ServiceController> SelectedServices
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedServices;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_selectedServices == null) return;
                _selectedServices = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedServices");
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<ServiceController> Services
        {
            get
            {
                _services.Clear();
                var curenntServices = Utils.UpdateServices(ComputerNames);
                foreach (var service in curenntServices)
                    if (service.MachineName == SelectedComputer)
                        if (Utils.CustomerNameOf(service) == SelectedCustomer)
                            _services.Add(service);
                return _services;
            }
            set
            {
                //if (_services == null) return;
                _services = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Services");
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedServices");
            }
        }

        #endregion
```

I think I haven't fully understood `OnPropertyChanged()`. I thought whenever I call something like `OnPropertyChanged("Services")`anything bound to the property Services will be notified and grab the updated data. However it is not.. what am I doing wrong. Which information do you need besides my XAML?

Comment: Show us your ViewModel.

Comment: Do you need the properties of the service to be updated ? If yes you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the ViewModel

Comment: Bind the DataGrid.Itemssource properly. For ViewModel property, set 
 the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. It's used to notify the control that the property value has changed.  Once check Binding="{Binding DisplayName, , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay }"/>

Comment: This is only the Services Property. There is also a Customers and a Computers section.

Comment: So what error you are facing?

Comment: You forgot to post your `StartService()` method.

Comment: Sorry, I think, I'm way too confused on this topic. I need to refactor what my actual problem is :D.

Comment: That getter in `Services` is very, very bad. You should never do that. The getter should simply return the collection. Repopulate it, *only as needed*, elsewhere. When you start a service, simply update the relevant ServiceController in `Services` (if there is one already), or add it (if it's not already there). The ServiceController itself should implement INPC, and when you add an item to the ObservableCollection, it will raise any needed notifications on its own.

Comment: Yea I changed the whole thing. I'm now setting everything to the new values when the influencing values change. Can you look at my most  recent question. It has most of the important code and an update on where I am stuck rn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you should change is this:

```
        set
        {
            if (_selectedServices == null) return;
            _selectedServices = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedServices");
        }
```

_selectedServices is null initially and it will remain so. 
Setting it will always fail because it'll always just return.

I suggest you always use curly braces as well for an if, by the way. Always put your statement on the next line.

```
  if (_selectedServices == null) 
     {
         // this is a terrible idea because it will always be true and your setter stops the property being set
          return;
     }
```